# Is implementing method for .Xib file in .m and .h against MVC?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Is it okay to define and implement methods in .h and .m file for Xib views or is it against MVC model concept? I am assuming the .h and .m files are part of the views and the methods that are defined and implemented in .h and .m files should only be initializing methods and the other action methods for button action should be implemented in the view controller that uses the .xib view. I have also seen methods for button action defined in the view's .m and .h file but I assumed the action should only be defined in the view controller.
Can you please explain if I am assuming wrong or my assumption of MVC is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what are the methods intended to be for. The view can be enriched with methods if they are part of the view business. Like transformers that select colors from numbers, or code to manage complex controls. If the methods are not related to the model, why not?